# unordered_map<unsigned long, Camera*> returns a Access Violation Exception unpon insert

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So the title really does sum it up but the unordered_map is created on the stack and the code I use to insert into it as is follows

```
void CameraContainer::addCamera(Scene::Camera* e){
    stored_cameras.insert({ e->getGUID(), e }); 
}
```

GUID will return a unsigned int

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 2

I don't know if it matters, but the class which this code belongs to is inherited by another class and it's through the other class that this one has it's functions called.
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing `e` or `this` (if stored_cameras is a member) is a null/invalid pointer

Comment: So this is a managed C++ question then I guess? Or C++/CLI or whatever they call it nowadays?

Comment: In fact it's almost certainly the CameraContainer you're calling `addCamera` on is a null pointer, since the Raw View states you're accessing an object at 0x20 which is 32 bytes (an int, or maybe a virtual function table pointer?) after 0 which is the offset of stored_cameras in your class

Comment: @Salgar that's what I think too, but Why! it's not a pointer :/

Comment: @Salgar I can confirm that e is not a nullptr and it's all there.
#Jeff normal c++ here, just using the STD:: libraries.

Comment: @JoshuaWaring show the code where you're calling addCamera, or if it's the same object, the code calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Salgar 
The issue as you said was I'm calling the function on a nullptr, 
which was hidden from me because I get the pointer from the Lua Registery, obviously before it exists there.

Thank you

Comment: I think we've all done stackoverflow incorrectly here :)